# How can i show warnings in wordpress when a post is updated with a session variable?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show some warnings when a post (some custom type) is updated/saved in wp-admin. For example, the post was not updated because some input field is empty - and i want to show message about it. I think it is possible to reach this with session variable.

I tried in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_postdata' );
function my_save_postdata( $post_id, $post ) {
if ( 'preorders' == $post->post_type) { // only for post type preorders
if ( !session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}

    // check if field is set and not empty
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_new_field'] ) || ($_POST['my_new_field'] == '')  ) {
    $_SESSION["admin_notices"] = "error!";
    return;
    }

    $my_new_field =  $_POST['my_new_field'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_new_field ', $my_new_field);
    unset ($_SESSION['admin_notices']);
}
}
```

And this code is presented in my metabox content:

```
if ((isset($_SESSION["admin_notices"])) && ($_SESSION["admin_notices"] != '')) {
    echo '<div class="preordersavewarning"><p>'.$_SESSION["admin_notices"].'</p></div>';
    }
    else {
    echo "no warnings";
    }
```

But it does not work properly - it always shows me "no warnings" message. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the problem solved. I just forgot to add:

```
if ( !session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}
```

also at the beginning of metabox content. Now it works!